# MAC 10.10 Yosemite - Terminal: - bash: [SomeCommand] command not found?

Tags: bash, terminal, osx-yosemite

I dont know why but when I write any commands in my terminal. It always show me -bash:[SomeCommand] command not found. I dont know if it's about my path -bash: /user/local/php5/bin:/user/local/mysql/bin: No such file or directory or anything else. It was my first time that I use the terminal and I don't know what happened.

Comment: In case you don't get what @MichaelM is suggesting, open the file `~/.profile` in `TextEdit` and add a line like this near the bottom `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/user/local/php5/bin:/user/local/mysql/bin`  That is all one single line. Then start a new Terminal and try again.

Comment: When I try to open the file :open -a TextEdit .profile -> The file /Users/sothearavychan/.profile does not exist.

Comment: You may be using `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login`

Comment: Or your PATH may be set in `/etc/profile` for all users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing the regular bin directories. Here's what my $PATH looks like on a fresh Yosemite:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```